# Sorting an ArrayList of Int[] on multiple indexes

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I currently have an `ArrayList` of `int[]`. The `int[]` has 5 elements. I want to be able to sort this `ArrayList` on the basis of the 2nd and 4th indexes of the my `int[]`. How do I do this in Java?

Comment: Can you explain exactly what it is you're trying to do? What does `on the basis of the 2nd and 4th indexes` mean?

Comment: So for example if i had the following Array List [1,4,6,8,9] [1,3,6,7,8] [1,4,6,7,9] the order would be [1,3,6,7,8] [ 1,4,6,7,9] [ 1,4,6,8,9] i.e i would first sort on the 2nd index and if that is same then sort by the 4th index...

Answer (score 2):

```
package com.sandbox;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Sandbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<int[]>();
        list.add(new int[]{1, 4, 6, 8, 9});
        list.add(new int[]{1,3,6,7,8});
        list.add(new int[]{1,4,6,7,9});
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<int[]>() {
            public int compare(int[] o1, int[] o2) {
                int compare = Integer.compare(o1[1], o2[1]);
                //if they're equal on this element then compare the next element
                return compare == 0 ? Integer.compare(o1[3], o2[3]) : compare;
            }
        });
        for (int[] ints : list) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ints));
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output:

> [1, 3, 6, 7, 8]
>   [1, 4, 6, 7, 9]
>   [1, 4, 6, 8, 9]

Comment: Ahh brilliant thanks a lot!!... how would i extend this if i wanted to sort on a number of paramterised indexes i.e not necessirly 2 and 4?  would i declare a constructor?

Comment: That really depends on how you're going to pass those in.  But if I were to guess, I'd extract the `Comparator` to its own class and give it a constructor on it where you pass in the indexes you want to sort by.

Comment: I can't seem to call Integer.compare() ?

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom Comparator like this

```
    class IntArrayComparator implements Comparator<int[]> {
        private final int[] ai;

        IntArrayComparator(int[] ai) {
            this.ai = ai;
        }

        @Override
        public int compare(int[] a1, int[] a2) {
            for (int i : ai) {
                int c = Integer.compare(a1[i], a2[i]);
                if (c != 0) {
                    return c;
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

note that Integer.compare(int, int) is added in Java 7, in earlier versions use

```
int c = (a1[i] < a2[i]) ? -1 : a1[i] == a2[i] ? 0 : 1;
```

Comment: Ahh thanks just implementing this but am unbale to call Integer.compare ... any idea why?